# Javascript linter that catches incorrect use of `this`

Tags: javascript

One of my most common mistakes in writing Javascript code is using `this` inside a callback or scheduled timer, where it is no longer valid.  The standard practice is to capture `this` in another variable, commonly `self`, and use that variable inside the callback.  But if I forget to do this, or make a change that moves code from within the method to a callback without changing `this` to `self`, my code will now throw an error.

I want my linter to flag this for me.  My current linter, [jshint](https://github.com/jshint/jshint) (version 2.9.4) does not catch this, at least not in the way I currently have it configured.

Is there any linter available that will flag improper uses of `this` in Javascript code?

Comment: The problem is that it's hard to define what an "improper" use of this is...

Comment: You should use `.bind()`, or, better yet, lambdas.

Comment: This is not an incorrect use of `this`. It's just that `this` won't be what you want. No linter can read your mind to know what you want. So not possible.

Comment: By writing your callbacks with `() => {}` instead of `function () {}`, the `this` inside the callback is, in most cases, the `this` you expect. (About browsers compatibility: http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions and https://babeljs.io)

Comment: So your linter would never allow you to use functions with the new keyword? Are you sure you want to cut off that piece of functionality from yourself?

Comment: There's static type systems for JS that catch this kind of thing now. TypeScript is one example

Comment: You can also use strict mode to ensure that misuse of `this` throws an exception instead of silently polluting the global object.

Comment: @SLaks Yes, I totally agree that I should.  So can some linter tell me when I forgot to do that?

Comment: @JordanS I presume you mean that it is hard to determine *with static analysis* an improper use of of `this` is.  There is no question that I have used `this` improperly when the code throws an exception.  So is it really impossible to determine this with static analysis?

Comment: @christopher Ideally the linter would not flag any valid uses of `this` ... only cases where it will be undefined at runtime.  Is it impossible to know this in a static analysis?

Comment: @PMV I think I am using this.  But I'd prefer that the linter find this problem rather than throwing an exception at runtime.

Comment: @MikeKistler There is no such thing as an invalid use of `this`. All uses are valid. What you are asking is like using `var a = 0` in various places, but wanting some of them to be `var a = false` instead, and asking for a linter to say that. A linter can't know that you wanted a different thing than what you wrote!

Comment: Static analysis just isn't possible in all cases. Any use of `call`, `bind`, or `apply` make static analysis prone to false positives.  As a popular example, in JQuery, a callback will use `call` to pass the DOM element that the handler is attached to as `this`. A linter that yelled at your error would also yell at legitimate JQuery handlers.